# Save form data into local json file using jquery

Tags: javascript, json, forms, jquery

I have a basic form with some input fields. I want to save the form data into a json file on submitting the form.
The format of the saved data in the json file should be like this.

```
[
    {"title":"some text","description":"some text","info":"some text","username":"some name"},
    {"title":"some text","description":"some text","info":"some text","username":"some name"},
    {"title":"some text","description":"some text","info":"some text","username":"some name"}
]
```

I tried doing this by using this code, but no data is saved in my 'story.json file'

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST', 
       dataType: 'json', 
       url: 'story.json', 
       data: $(this).serialize(), 
       success: function(data) { 
           alert(data.message); 
       },
       failure: function (data) {
           alert('Please try again');
       }
    });
 });
```

I want to save this form data on my local file.
Please help me to find the correct way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: I would go out and say that unless you are good with configuring your http server, you need a server side language, have you got one?

Comment: you can save to localStorage for browsers that support it without needing server... is this a viable solution?

Comment: yes, not possible without a  server side language.Thats the answer.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to post data to a simple php file...

like `url: 'story.php'`
In that php file create a 'story.json' using `fopen` and store that json

EDIT: if you want to use `serialize()` than use someting like this

```
data:{'mydata':$(this).serialize()}
```

and in php file

```
parse_str($_POST['mydata'],$newarray) ;

echo json_encode($newarray);
```

Comment: ok..So how can i save this form data in the above format in a json object using .serialize() or .serializeArray() method.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript cannot save to a file unless it's a FireFox plugin.

What you do is post a form (sent it to the webserver) then let server side script handle it.

Serialize does not turn the form values into a JSON string:

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

And when you use $.post then you have to return false in the $('form').submit(function() or the browser will submit the form for you.

Submitting a form is when you click a button and the whole page goes white for a moment and then you get a new page.

Ajax ($.post, $.get, $.getJson ...) is when you send information to the server without refreshing the page. Google maps is an excellent example.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the serialize method on the form jQuery object does not return a JSON representation of its data. It returns a querystring representation of its data. As has been mentioned above, you will need to use a server side script to interpret (and manipulate) sent data and store it in a file as JSON.